# Adding spaces in between printed alphabet

Tags: php

I found this handy code in order to print the alphabet horizontally across the page. I would like to put a few spaces in between the letters since they are bunched really close together. Thanks for any help!

```
$alphabet = range('A', 'Z');
$table = '<table>';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($alphabet); $i++) {                    
    $table .= '<td>' . $alphabet[$i] . '</td>';
}
$table .= '</table>';
echo $table;
```

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: This code does not output valid HTML. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp

Comment: You need some **<tr >** and **</tr >** tags in there.

Comment: @Scott... Please see my answer. To answer your question, it's not valid HTML since you don't have a row (no `<tr>` tag) in your table.

Comment: Thanks mituw16, your code worked, It says I have 6 minutes before I can mark an answer as correct

Comment: @Scott, Great! Happy to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use CSS, try adding a `cellspacing` attribute to your table.

```
$alphabet = range('A', 'Z');
$table = '<table cellspacing='10'><tr>';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($alphabet); $i++) {                    
   $table .= '<td>' . $alphabet[$i] . '</td>';
}
$table .= '</tr></table>';
echo $table;
```

This adds 10 pixels between the cells.

You could also do this with CSS like so..

`table tr td { margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; }`

Also, your code is not currently out putting a valid HTML table. I fixed that too ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it across CSS

```
td { padding-bottom : 20px; }
```

Comment: Excuse, for <td> you'd write: td { padding-bottom : 20px; }

Comment: OP stated that he wants to add **horizontal** spacing between cells. This will do nothing for OP's question